# Java files do not reflect changes made in Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse EE

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I have a dynamic web project in eclipse juno EE. Whenever I make changes to the java files in the project, the changes are not reflected. The old version of the file runs. Can someone help!

Comment: do you redeploy your project in tomcat after editing the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to configure the tomcat server in Eclipse and disable Auto Reloading but enable Auto Publishing, so that JVM hotswap can be used.  Here is an article talking in detail about it. [How to Set Up Hot Code Replacement with Tomcat and Eclipse](http://blog.redfin.com/devblog/2009/09/how_to_set_up_hot_code_replacement_with_tomcat_and_eclipse.html).

It is worth mentioning that there is a commercial product named JRebel that is much more powerful than JVM HotSwap. Here is a link [comparing JRebel vs HotSwap](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/features/) if you are interested.

Comment: JRebel looks cool. Do you have an experience with this tool? Is it fast when you are changing interfaces, adding/ removing classes, etc.?

Comment: I did not notice much performance difference, but I could not say that for sure. JRebel supports much more classes/interface related changes and handles reflection API much better.

Answer (score 0):

You have to either redeploy whole application or run it in debug mode in which some hot deploy (if you do not change method's signatures) is possible.